# Hijacking the Back Button - Can't Segue - Swift

Tags: swift, segue, back-button

I need the Back Button to take me to the previous hierarchical view and not the previous view visited, and save some data before it does so in the "actionSave" function. The code below displays the familiar back button, executes the function but then takes me to the previous view visited.

```
// Takeover Back Button
self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = false
let newBackButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "", style: .Plain, target: self, action: "actionSave:")
navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.backBarButtonItem = newBackButton
```

How can I force it to a particular view? The storyboard isn't allowing me to link from the Back Button to the specific view so I could use a Segue.

Answer (score 0):

You can access all your ViewControllers in Stack with:

```
yourViewControllerYouNeed = self.navigationController?.viewControllers[index] as! UIViewController //(or your specific class)
```

And you are able to change to a specific one by using:

```
mainVC?.visibleViewController.navigationController?.presentViewController(yourViewControllerYouNeed, animated: false, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you set up the segue in the Storyboard:

1. Control drag from the File's Owner icon of the last `ViewController` to your specific `ViewController`.
2. Choose "Present Modally" from the pop-up.

[image]

After that you can perform segue this way:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let backButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Back", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: "goBack")
    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButton

}

func goBack() {
    performSegueWithIdentifier("viewB", sender: nil)
}
```

Comment: That half works. When it brings up the parent View the title bar is missing and the page begins at the very top of the screen overwriting the time/battery information. Am investigating.

Comment: Accept the answer if it helps you.